# Mute command failing with "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'"

Tags: python, discord.py

I coded a mute command for discord.py but it's not working for some reason , I am new to coding so I don't know much.

Here is the code

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx,time,member : discord.Member):
muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(769146178469232650)

await member.add_roles(muted_role)

time = convert(time)

await ctx.send(member.mention + " has been muted")

await asyncio.sleep(time)

await member.remove_roles(muted_role)

await ctx.send(f"{member} has been unmuted , time is up!")
```

and here is the error that I get

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_x` and `utils.get` both return None if they can't find anything matching.
Common causes include:

- Not subscribed to the relevant intent.
- Wrong key
- Bot not logged in, and trying to grab objects from cache
- Bot cannot "see" the object

I'm pretty sure you didn't enable `intents.members`, that's why the argument `member` is a NoneType, enable intents, [here's how](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?)